# How to convert the 4-byte `char` array to one variable of type `unsigned long`?

Tags: c

```c
union sUnion {
    unsigned long hex;
    float var;
};

void Testcode(void)
{
    char rdata[4] = { 0xd7, 0xa3, 0x40, 0xc1 };         // to DEC: -12.04
    char ctemp[100];

    union sUnion r;
    r.hex = 0xc140a3d7;       //<=== ??????

    sprintf(ctemp, "hex = %x, float = %f", r.hex, r.var);
}
```

I want to put the data from `rdata` into the `r.hex` variable to produce a result of `-12.04`

Comment: Is `sizeof (unsigned long)` 4 on your system? (Also you should probably make `rdata`'s element type `unsigned char` instead of `char`)

Comment: basically `r.hex = (rdata[3] << 24) | (rdata[2] << 16) | (rdata[1] << 8) | (rdata[0] << 0);`.

Comment: Thank you so much! My problem has been solved!

Comment: @tehos Beware that this kind of solution, although easy and fast, triggers undefined behavior, and only works if: 1) the platform is little-endian; 2) `float` is an IEEE754 binary32 and `sizeof(float) == 4`; 3) `sizeof(unsigned long) == 4`; 4) `CHAR_BIT == 8` (this last one may be ignored if your program will only run on Windows or on POSIX-compliant platforms). Thus, it is discouraged especially if you have to send/receive data over the network.

Answer (score -1):

If assertion fails change the type of the integer

```
_Static_assert (sizeof(unsigned long) == 4, "assert1");
#define INTLENGTH sizeof(unsigned long)

//endianess independent
unsigned long covert1(void *varr, int endianness)
{
    unsigned char *arr = varr;
    unsigned long result;

    #define MAXINDEX (INTLENGTH -1)

    if(endianess)
        result = (unsigned long)arr[0] + ((unsigned long)arr[1] << 8) + ((unsigned long)arr[2] << 16) + ((unsigned long)arr[3] << 24);
    else
        result = (unsigned long)arr[MAXINDEX - 0] + ((unsigned long)arr[MAXINDEX - 1] << 8) + ((unsigned long)arr[MAXINDEX - 2] << 16) + ((unsigned long)arr[MAXINDEX - 3] << 24);
    return result;
}

//arr has to have seme endianness as integers
unsigned long covert(void *arr)
{
    unsigned long result;
    memcpy(&result, arr, sizeof(result));
    return result;
}
```